# Laravel 5, PHP 5.6, Plesk 11.5 issues with paths

Tags: php, apache, laravel, nginx

Sorry if the similar thread already exists.

I have the following issue, I have installed Laravel 5 on my server with Plesk 11.5 running apache. The Docroot is pointed to `/httpdocs/public`

The issue is that inside public I have `assets` folder with images etc.

when I try to access `site.com/assets/images/5.jpg` I get 404 with Nginx !!!

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.
David.

Answer (score 0):

The folder `/ressources/assets` should only be used to store your SASS, LESS, etc... files that shouldn't be pushed on production server.

If you want to store images, css, etc... you should do so directly in the `public/[images/css/...]` folder of Laravel.

Comment: The issue is I cant even access file 5.jpg from public directory. Do you know what may be issue ?